# Rails - search through has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, has-many

I have these models:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :car_services
end
class CarService < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car
  belongs_to :car_service_definition
end
class CarServiceDefinition < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :car_services
end
```

I am trying to find out if the currently selected car has a certain service - trying to do it this way:

```
airbag = car.car_services.car_service_definitions.where('service_type = "Airbag"').first
```

But this query doesn't work because of the wrong using model associations.

How do I find out, if the current car has some airbags?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your migrations are fine

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :car_services
end

class CarService < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car
  belongs_to :car_service_list
  has_and_belongs_to_many :car_service_definitions
end

class CarServiceDefinition < ActiveRecord::Base
end

airbag = car.car_services.car_service_definitions.where(service_type: 'AirBag').first
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, from the look of the relationships, I assume that `car_services` is the rich join table of `cars` and `car_service_definitions`

What you can do is to set up `has_many :through` relationship on both `car` and `car_service_definition`

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :car_services
  has_many :car_service_definitions, through: :car_services
end

class CarService < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car
  belongs_to :car_service_definition
end

class CarServiceDefinition < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :car_services
  has_many :cars, through: :car_services
end
```

And then if you want to find airbag, it would be like this

```
airbag = car.car_service_definitions.where("car_service_definitions.service_type" => 'AirBag').first
```

But if you want to check if the `car` has `air_bag`, could just write a method like this

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  def has_air_bag?
    car_service_definitions.where("car_service_definitions.service_type" => 'AirBag').count > 0
  end
end
```